# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'foundation'

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails-4

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'foundation'

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved! Foundation installs Jquery.js by default. I had an extra Jquery.min.js that I installed myself which was conflicting with Foundation.

Simply remove one of the two for it to work.